# Convergence of generalized periodic continued fractions

Tags: convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

Consider a periodic continued fraction
$$x=\cfrac{a_1}{b_1+ \cfrac{a_2}{b_2+ \cfrac{\ddots}{\ddots b_{k-1}+ \cfrac{a_1}{b_1 + \ddots }}} }$$
for some sequence $a_1,\cdots, a_k$ and $b_1,\cdots, b_{k-1}$.

The wikipedia page on the "convergence problem":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_problem#Periodic_continued_fractions

gives an if and only if condition for $x$ to converge in terms of the roots of a quadratic involving the $k$th and $(k-1)$th convergents of $x$. Unfortunately, the reference is 120 years old and written in German.

We are looking for a modern reference, or a short proof of this fact.

Comment: The proof in [Jones & Thron](https://zbmath.org/0603.30009) (section $3.2$) looks pretty good (but not *short* anyway).